# Using WinAPI to control monitors

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I currently have a command line program that sends various commands through my graphics card driver's API, but the driver isn't bugfree. What I'd like is to use the Windows API to enable/disable certain connected monitors, except I have no experience with Windows programming.

I've checked out the list of Windows APIs and don't really know where to look for this functionality, so if someone could help me out here that'd be fantastic.

Note: I'm using VS2010, coding in C++.

Comment: This might be a starting point:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145179(v=vs.85).aspx